# VBA: How to call an Userform Object by its name (Loop)

Tags: excel, vba

I just started to learn VBA for a project and i have a userform where i have multiple sliders that give me values that i want to use to build a 2D Array with For loops.

My Array is 5 by 5 and it is "Symmetric" (1 as diagonal, Thus I only need one side for the values).

I obtain the matrix values after converting values obtained from sliders in the GUI, which i named Sld1v2 (for row 1, col 2), Sld1v3 (for row1, col3) etccc.

I am thus looking for a way to call the right Slider (by its custom name) in the for loops but i cannot figure how i can do it, can you help me ? I currently have a Type Error, when running the line --> JudgementMatrix(lig,col) = JudgementVector(....)

Following you can see the Excel Version of what i want to code and my attempt of a script.
I hope my request is clear :)

**EDIT:** By changing Variant type to Double for the Matrix and Vector (since i saw my vector had different types within). I now get an error when i call the function Array. But the thing is that Array returns a variant! --> Filled the Vector manually

[Screenshot of the Excel of what i want to code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJF20.png)

```
       Dim JudgementVector(16) As Double
Dim JudgementMatrix(4, 4) As Double
Dim lig As Integer
Dim col As Integer

For i = 0 To 16
    If i < 8 Then
    JudgementVector(i) = (1 / (9 - i))
    Else
        If i >= 8 Then
        JudgementVector(i) = i - 7
        End If
    End If
Next i


For lig = 0 To 4
    For col = 0 To 4
        If col = lig Then
        JudgementMatrix(lig, col) = 1
        Else
            If col > lig Then
                    JudgementMatrix(lig, col) = JudgementVector(UserForm1.Controls(["sld"&lig&"v"&col]).Value + 8)
            Else
                If lig > col Then
                    JudgementMatrix(lig, col) = 1 / JudgementMatrix(col, lig)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next col
Next lig
```

Comment: You only need `UserForm1.Controls("sld" & lig & "v" & col)` to refer to the controls.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! I have tried this but i get a Syntax Error (red text) expecting a separator or a ")"

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it didnt like having "Text" & variable & "Text" & Variable
so i by passed it by creating temp values to combine step by step.

```
Dim JudgementVector(16) As Double
Dim JudgementMatrix(4, 4) As Double
Dim lig As Integer
Dim col As Integer
Dim Temp1 As String
Dim Temp2 As String
Dim Temp3 As String
```

'    JudgementVector = ([{1 / 9, 1 / 8, 1 / 7, 1 / 6, 1 / 5, 1 / 4, 1 / 3, 1 / 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}])

```
For i = 0 To 16
    If i < 8 Then
    JudgementVector(i) = (1 / (9 - i))
    Else
        If i >= 8 Then
        JudgementVector(i) = i - 7
        End If
    End If
Next i


For lig = 0 To 4
    For col = 0 To 4
        If col = lig Then
        JudgementMatrix(lig, col) = 1
        Else
            If col > lig Then
            Temp1 = "sld" & lig + 1
            Temp2 = "v" & col + 1
            Temp3 = Temp1 & Temp2
            
                    JudgementMatrix(lig, col) = JudgementVector(UserForm1.Controls(Temp3) + 8)

            Else
                If lig > col Then
                    JudgementMatrix(lig, col) = 1 / JudgementMatrix(col, lig)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next col
Next lig
```